# JQuery Alternate of YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName

Tags: jquery, yui

Can any one tell me the alternate of YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName in JQuery?

It can be done somewhat like this :

```
function(elemName, tag, root) {
 $("form[name='" + root.name + "'] " + tag + "." + elemName);
}
```

But what if a function is also passed in it as another parameter like that in YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName?

Comment: go to the docs?  they are well [documented](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Apart from anything else you need to make it clear what `YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName` does, don't expect us to go to another site to read *their* documentation in order for us to point you to another resource available - *probably* - via jQuery's documentation. Incidentally, jQuery documentation is at: [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: and YUI is also great, if that works for you and if you know that very well then why jQuery?